How to prevent apps from making background sound using adb?
I use a dating app, and this app makes sound in the background even though it's not running. It's very annoying because it's like telling everyone around me "hey, this guy is using dating app".
I found cmd appops set app_name PLAY_AUDIO deny, but it denies all the audio.
I don't want to deny all the audio because I usually have a phone chat or audio message on the app.
I want to deny specific audio in both background and foreground. What's the command? And where can I find the related commands about audio?

So you are sure the audio is not coming from a notification (see Android notification history)?

@Robert Although I didn't check notification history, but I did check Audio playback (lastly played comes first) and sure it's this app making sound.
